# what are duty of locale and locale-gen commands?

Tags: 12.04, locale

I know in order to understand how commands work, we should use man page. But for command locale and locale-gen. I did not  got the exact meaning and their duty. I need some more description about their jobs and the relation between **locale** and **locale-gen**. Based on man locale:

> locale - Get locale-specific information.

ok what is locale??

> DESCRIPTION
>          The locale program writes information about the current locale environ���
>          ment, or all locales, to standard output.

what is locale environment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Wikipedia :

> In computing, a locale is a set of parameters that defines the user's language, country and any special variant preferences that the user wants to see in their user interface. Usually a locale identifier consists of at least a language identifier and a region identifier.

The `locale` programs will output a set of shell variables and their values. These are the variables that alter the behaviour of some commands regarding the language, character sets usage and so on.
From my system :

```
benoit@thorgal:~s locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
benoit@thorgal:~$
```

This tells those commands, which listen, to use American English and UTF8 encoding for the special characters.
If I change the value of **LANG** and put fr_FR.UTF-8 instead, then commands, that support it, will write their output in French instead of English. Of course, only, if the French translation is installed.

For the `locale-gen` command, I think that the first paragraph of its man page is self-explaining :

> Compiled  locale  files  take  about 50MB of disk space, and most users
>          only need few locales.  In order to save disk  space,  compiled  locale
>          files  are not distributed in the locales package, but selected locales
>          are automatically generated when this package is installed  by  running
>          the locale-gen program.

When you run `locale-gen` or `locale-gen <locale code>` you compile the needed locale file(s), allowing commands to use the locale specified within the environments variables displayed by `locale`.

Example: `locale-gen en_US.UTF8`

You can get the available locale codes by using the command `locale -a`.

Comment: What do these locale files that take up megabytes of space contain?

Comment: If I don't run locale-gen, what is the default location? because 50 MB for docker containers is too much...